# Image as a toggle hide/reveal button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello Stack Overflow,

I am a photographer building an html website, so excuse my ignorance. I am looking to use an image as a button that reveals a set of text on click. I can't seem to find a way to do this without having a button over the image. Is there an easier way? or perhaps is there another word other than "button" that I am lacking in searching for this?

Update:
I again apologize for my ignorance, I feel I lacked clarity in my question. I used a toggle/reveal button on my page and I want the text to start hidden so that the photograph reveals the text,rather than removes it.

See site:
http://lyonswork.com/

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Where should this text appear and how large is the image(s) that you're talking about?

Comment: So far I have used the onclick attribute for an img tag (there is the possibility I am doing this incorrectly). I am attempting to have the text appear centered and below the image. I will include my code in the question prompt. Thank you Zohir & Rickard for your quick responses.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use several options, 1 option is to use the css :hover state. This allows the user to hover over the image and then reveal a text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `onclick` attribute on `img` tag. If it works then you just have to write your javascript code.

Comment: Thank you Kuldeep, this is actually the approach I was hoping to take. For some mistake of my own when I remove the button tag and try use the image tag the onclick attribute stops working

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like that ?

(just click on figure element to show / hide text over image)

```js
const myImage = document.querySelector('#my-image')
  ;
myImage.onclick =()=>
  {
  myImage.classList.toggle('noCaption')
  }
```

```css
figure#my-image {
  position: relative
  }
figure#my-image img {
  width:   500px;
  height:  300px;
  border:  1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px;
  }
figure#my-image figcaption {
  position: absolute;
   bottom:   3px;
   left:     3px;
  display:  block;
   width:    492px;  /* 500 - (2*4) */
   padding:  4px;
  color:    white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
q {
  display:    block;
  text-align: center;  
  }
cite {
  float: right;
  }
figure#my-image.noCaption figcaption {
  display: none !important;
  }
```

```html
<figure id="my-image" class="noCaption">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="something revelant" />
  <figcaption>
    <q>A people who do not read is a risk for democracy</q>
    <cite>Fréderic Paulin</cite>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

> **OR**

```js
const myImage = document.querySelector('#my-image');

myImage.onclick=()=>
  {
  myImage.classList.toggle('noCaption')
  }
```

```css
figure#my-image {
  width:   506px;
  }
figure#my-image  * {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:      100%;
  }
figure#my-image img {
  border:  1px solid grey;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  }
figure#my-image figcaption {
  padding:  .4em 0 .3em 0;
  color:   white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
q {
  text-align: center;  
  }
cite {
  width: 100%;
  padding : .7em .5em 0 0;
  text-align: right;
  }
figure#my-image.noCaption figcaption {
  display: none !important;
  }
```

```html
<figure id="my-image" class="noCaption">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="something revelant" />
  <figcaption>
    <q>A people who do not read is a risk for democracy</q>
    <cite>Fréderic Paulin</cite>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Mister Jojo thank you for your response, I'm sorry I didn't comment directly to you earlier. This is helpful, but unfortunately not what I need. I'm looking for the text to appear underneath my image rather than on top of it as a caption. Is it possible to do this where it appears below and still maintains regular text formatting. Again apologies if I am misusing terms or unclear in any way.

Comment: @tcl2122 I made the change for that, with the 2 ways to position the text. These are just adjustments to CSS. The positioning of the text in relation to the image was not in the question.

Comment: @tcl2122 So,  are this ones are good enough for you ? will you validate my answer, or giving a feedback about it ?

Comment: Mister Jojo I am so new to this site I don't even know howto give feed back. The code you suggested was good, but didn't exactly solve my problem. I updated my question for specificity. Happy to give you good feedback once I figure out how.

Comment: @tcl2122 the problem is that your request becomes more and more incomprehensible, and that I risk losing a lot of time to guess what you are looking for!